# AMP: amp-script is not running

Tags: javascript, scroll, amp-html

I am trying to use `amp-script` to toggle a class on my `nav` (top menubar) when the window starts to scroll.  The effect is to turn the fixed nav from semi-transparent to solid white.

Here is what I tried ...

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AMP Page</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp-custom>
    nav {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      color: white;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 10;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .opaque {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }

    .hero {
      height: max(25vh, 250px);
      width: 100vw;
      background: red;
    }

    .spacer {
      height: 4em;
      background: blue;
      margin: 0.5em;
    }
  </style>
  <meta name="amp-script-src" content="sha384-bpf6fazoofAb6S1aK0_hOIa1g6nDaC_SPbTuSJsMxEzAPc11oKjAnJZmeFAMKc2p ">
</head>
<body>
  <script id="scroll-listener" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
    document.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
      console.log('scrolled!!');
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("topnav").className = "opaque";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("topnav").className = "";
      }
    }
  </script>
  <nav id="topnav">
    <h1>ACME Inc.</h1>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <header class="hero"></header>
    <article>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
    </article>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately the script has no effect at all.  I've also placed `console.log` statements to see if I get any scroll events reported at all - and nothing shows up in the console.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

UPDATE: Just to make sure that this works as a "non-AMP" page, I changed the line in the example above:

```html
<script id="scroll-listener" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">...</script>
```

to this ...

```html
<script id="scroll-listener" type="text/javascript">...</script>
```

and the site works as expected.  So I know for sure that the javascript as written does what I want it to do.  The issue is entirely with the way AMP is handling the script.

Comment: I see a red header bar with white (logo) text. On scroll, the blue rows scroll but the white header text is fixed. That seems to be the consistent with the above code. What am I missing?

Comment: The toggle on the class does not occur.  The header bar should change to a white background as soon as scrolling starts.

Comment: @JayGray you may need to click "full page" to see the code snippet run properly.

Comment: OK, looks like `Element.scrollTop` is not supported. See: https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/blob/main/web_compat_table.md. But there may be another way to do what your want. Take a look at https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-fx-collection/?format=websites. I have (but can't find) an example that shrinks the header on scroll but fixes the header text. Will post back when I find it (done by https://github.com/aghassemi

Comment: @JayGray Let me know if you can find something because I can seem to find anything that would support it.  I've tried using the `amp-position-observer` but it doesn't allow class toggling!

Comment: Perhaps you can tailor these examples (none does exactly what you need but some are 'close'): 1) https://codepen.io/aghassemi/pen/jxvzzq 2) https://codepen.io/aghassemi/full/wyMEWP 3) https://codepen.io/aghassemi/full/EwrMoP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you don't understand how amp-script works, which is strange, because there are examples in the official documentation.

Try this example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My AMP Page</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1" />
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body {
        -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <noscript
      ><style amp-boilerplate>
        body {
          -webkit-animation: none;
          -moz-animation: none;
          -ms-animation: none;
          animation: none;
        }
      </style></noscript
    >
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <meta name="amp-script-src" content="sha384-nPCFvs2yYOVX1DFcHvkEUY1aC6PdG8FAgPUG16rZwxfQJOPh_pM1rA-oUzDsg8pk" />
    <style amp-custom>
      nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 10;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .opaque {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
      }

      .hero {
        height: max(25vh, 250px);
        width: 100vw;
        background: red;
      }

      .spacer {
        height: 4em;
        background: blue;
        margin: 0.5em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <amp-script script="scroll-listener">
      <nav id="topnav">
        <h1>ACME Inc.</h1>
      </nav>
      <main id="main">
        <header class="hero"></header>
        <article>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
        </article>
      </main>
    </amp-script>

    <script id="scroll-listener" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
      function myFunction(event) {
        console.log('scrolled!!');
      }
      window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The example above probably won't help you do what you want, but at least now you'll understand how amp-script works.

amp-script often requires a custom event to be triggered and will not work immediately after the page loads. Read about it here: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/?format=websites#user-gestures

To complete this task, I recommend that you use the amp-position-observer and amp-animation components. Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My AMP Page</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1" />
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body {
        -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <noscript
      ><style amp-boilerplate>
        body {
          -webkit-animation: none;
          -moz-animation: none;
          -ms-animation: none;
          animation: none;
        }
      </style></noscript
    >
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-position-observer" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-position-observer-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-animation" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-animation-0.1.js"></script>

    <style amp-custom>
      nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        color: cyan;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 10;
        text-align: center;
      }

      h1 {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
      }

      .opaque {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
      }

      .hero {
        height: max(25vh, 250px);
        width: 100vw;
        background: red;
      }

      .spacer {
        height: 4em;
        background: blue;
        margin: 0.5em;
      }

      .scroll-effect {
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .top-anchor {
        position: relative;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top-anchor">
      <amp-position-observer on="enter:hideAnim.start; exit:showAnim.start" layout="nodisplay"></amp-position-observer>
    </div>
    <nav id="topnav">
      <span class="scroll-effect" id="scroll-effect"></span>
      <h1>ACME Inc.</h1>
    </nav>
    <main id="main">
      <header class="hero"></header>
      <article>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
      </article>
    </main>

    <amp-animation id="showAnim" layout="nodisplay">
      <script type="application/json">
        {
          "duration": "200ms",
          "fill": "both",
          "iterations": "1",
          "direction": "alternate",
          "animations": [
            {
              "selector": "#scroll-effect",
              "keyframes": [
                {
                  "opacity": "1",
                  "visibility": "visible"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      </script>
    </amp-animation>
    <amp-animation id="hideAnim" layout="nodisplay">
      <script type="application/json">
        {
          "duration": "200ms",
          "fill": "both",
          "iterations": "1",
          "direction": "alternate",
          "animations": [
            {
              "selector": "#scroll-effect",
              "keyframes": [{ "opacity": "0", "visibility": "hidden" }]
            }
          ]
        }
      </script>
    </amp-animation>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apparently you don't know how amp-position-observer works.  I tried using it first and it generated errors when I tried to toggle classes using it.  This too is a known limitation listed in the documentation.

Comment: @ra9r Don't write that I don't know how something works. After all, I showed you a working demo here, and I also used it earlier. All you have in this question is an example of incorrect use of amp-script. If you say that I don't know something, then give a real working example of how to do it correctly, and not just talk.

Comment: I did nothing more than used the exact same language you used to me.  Insulting isn't it?  Be more considerate in the future.  That said, you still don't understand that amp-position-observer cannot be used to toggle classes.

Comment: I didn't try to switch classes. Here's your comment on the question:  `The header bar should change to a white background as soon as scrolling starts. ra9r Aug 28 at 18:05`. This is exactly what I implemented. You don't seem to remember what you wrote about.