# When scrolling page I can't change the header styles in amp page

Tags: amp-html

I want to get offsetTop number in pixels when scrolling page.

I try to get offsetTop with amp-script component when scrolling page, but it returns "undefined" instead of number(px).

I also tried to do with amp-position-observer and amp-animation components, but in this case I have the following issue:
It only works when scrolling down, and doesn't work when scrolling up.

This is the part of code that should work when scrolling down:

```
<amp-position-observer intersection-ratios="0.7" on="enter:header-animation.start" layout="nodisplay" hidden=""></amp-position-observer>

<amp-animation id="header-animation" layout="nodisplay" hidden="">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "selector": ".header__logo",
            "duration": "0.25s",
            "keyframes": {
                "transform": "translate(-50%,-50%)"
            },
            "fill": "forwards"
        }
    </script>
</amp-animation>
```

This is the part of code that should work when scrolling up:

```
<amp-position-observer intersection-ratios="0.7" on="enter:header-animation-back.start" layout="nodisplay" hidden=""></amp-position-observer>

<amp-animation id="header-animation-back" layout="nodisplay" hidden="">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "selector": ".header__logo",
            "duration": "0.25s",
            "keyframes": {
                "transform": "translate(-50%,200%)"
            },
            "fill": "forwards"
        }
    </script>
</amp-animation>
```

Do you have any idea how this problem can be solved in google amp?
I would be very thankful for any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here are 4 sources that might help you: 1) https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw 2) https://codepen.io/aghassemi/pen/xYwNZr 3) https://codepen.io/aghassemi/pen/GOEWEz 4) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370461/how-to-scroll-to-top-in-amp-after-updating-a-state-on-successful-form-submission

Comment: Here I recently answered how to make a header animation when scrolling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63702946/7460038